# A KB is 2^10. Is a byte 2^0 or 2^1?

Tags: byte, hardware

I've searched around a little bit to no avail. I'm leaning towards a plain byte being 2^0 compared to a KB being 2^10, MB 2^20, GB 2^30, etc... Thanks in advance for the help.

Is a byte 2^0? Or 2^1? Any explanation would also be appreciated as I'm really not just looking for an answer so much as I'm looking for understanding.

Comment: To clarify what I'm using this information for...I'm trying to fit x 128Byte chips into a 1KB memory system. I'm stuck between having either 4 chips (where a byte = 2^1) or 8 chips (where a byte = 2^0). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It's 8. See my answer ;)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1541-2002 may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread your question, so I deleted my old answer:

```
1 Kilobyte = 1024 bytes.
```

So:

```
1 Kilobyte = 2^10 bytes
```

What you're asking is how much one byte is, in bytes. So the answer to that is easy:

```
1 byte = 1 byte
```

And yes you can express this as :

```
1 byte = 2^0 bytes
```

Because : *anything to the power of 0 is 1*

But saying 1 byte = 2^0 bytes is a bit of a ridiculous thing ;)

Cheat sheet, for future reference:

```
x^0 = 1
x^1 = x
```

Comment on your later comment:

```
 1KB memory bank system = 1024 bytes. 1024 / 128 bytes = 8 chips.
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. Now onto some 68k programming =).

Answer (score 0):

A bit (short for BInary Digit) is one if two values: 0 or 1, just like a normal base 10 digit would have 10 values: 0-9

A byte is 8 bits (8 binary digits), a kilobyte is 1024 bytes, or 8196 bits.

Comment: I kilobyte is generally 1024 bytes, although the SI unit says its 1000, it's not as common. 8 kilobits is 8000 bits, so 1 KiB is not exactly 8 Kb

Comment: I've always thought that since it was a base-2 numbering system the SI prefixes were rounded to the nearest power of two. Is this an incorrect assumption?

Comment: In the case for bits, it's never been true. Your old 28kbps modem is actually 28000kbps. You could argue though that in these days, a KB is also a 1000 bytes, but this has been changed somewhat recently. If you refer to the base-2 KB you're officially supposed to inject an `i`: KiB. For must programmers 1KB = 1024B though.